removing first and last character and empty spaces from a json file
I have given sets of different input files as shown sample below
cat out.txt

[
  {
    "regional_unit": "node",
    "source_name": "1753250187_SPS", 
    "technology": "STP", 
    "temporal_unit": "15min", 
    "timestamp_column_name": "collectTime", 
    "timestamp_column_pattern": "yyyyMMddHHmmss", 
    "vendor": "HUA"
  }
]

I want to read such files from the directory and want to remove [ & ] and also the empty spaces

You mean as in jq -c '.[]' out.txt? Do you want to modify the files in place or just output the result? Can the arrays have more than one element? Can you post the expected output?

Please [edit] your question and show us the output you would want from that example input. Also explain if you want this output in the same file, overwriting the original, or if you want it saved to a new file or just printed to the terminal.

To expand the top-most array into a set of objects, you may use jq like so:
$ jq '.[]' file
{
  "regional_unit": "node",
  "source_name": "1753250187_SPS",
  "technology": "STP",
  "temporal_unit": "15min",
  "timestamp_column_name": "collectTime",
  "timestamp_column_pattern": "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
  "vendor": "HUA"
}

If you want jq to produce "compact" output (which removes unnecessary whitespace), then add the -c (or --compact-output) option:
$ jq -c '.[]' file
{"regional_unit":"node","source_name":"1753250187_SPS","technology":"STP","temporal_unit":"15min","timestamp_column_name":"collectTime","timestamp_column_pattern":"yyyyMMddHHmmss","vendor":"HUA"}

This would produce one line of output per entry in the original array.
